# Eliminar registros dupliacos

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde se duplicaron los registros necesito eliminar los duplicados

**Tabla**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estructura de tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual seria el campo unico???

Comment: codlote  es el campo único

Comment: esto te puede ayudar https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/

Comment: Agrega por favor tu consulta

Answer (score 0):

Con el escenario que planteas:

```
create table dbo.duplicados (
 codlote varchar(10) not null,
 animal numeric(5,0) not null,
 peso numeric(18,2) not null,
 pesocava numeric(18,2),
 fecha datetime not null,
 fechacava datetime,
 codtipo char(5) not null,
 id numeric(1,0) not null,
 sexo char(1) not null,
 rendimiento numeric(18,4),
 ciclan bit,
 observaciones char(200),
 pesociclan numeric (18,2),
 LLAVESAP char(20),
 DCTOSAP char(20),
 FECHASAP datetime,
 identificador int);
 GO

 Insert Into dbo.duplicados
 (codlote
 ,animal 
 ,peso 
 ,pesocava
 ,fecha
 ,fechacava
 ,codtipo 
 ,id 
 ,sexo
 ,rendimiento 
 ,ciclan 
 ,observaciones 
 ,pesociclan 
 ,LLAVESAP 
 ,DCTOSAP 
 ,FECHASAP 
 ,identificador)
 Values
 ('18241',1,135.80,null,'20200312      08:38:05.060',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
 ('18241',1,135.80,null,'20200312 08:38:05.060',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
 ('18241',2,86.50 ,null,'20200312 08:38:35.557',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
 ('18241',2,86.50 ,null,'20200312 08:38:35.557',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
 ('18241',3,84.30 ,null,'20200312 08:40:48.037',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
 ('18241',3,84.30 ,null,'20200312 08:40:48.037',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
 ('18242',4,84.30 ,null,'20200312 08:40:48.037',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
 ('18242',4,84.30 ,null,'20200312 08:40:48.037',null,2,0,'M',0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
 GO
```

He cambiado las dos últimas filas, modificando el codLote, ya que indicas que ese campo debiera de ser único.

```
WITH Cte
 AS (SELECT duplicados.codlote
          , duplicados.animal
          , duplicados.peso
          , duplicados.pesocava
          , duplicados.fecha
          , duplicados.fechacava
          , duplicados.codtipo
          , duplicados.id
          , duplicados.sexo
          , duplicados.rendimiento
          , duplicados.ciclan
          , duplicados.observaciones
          , duplicados.pesociclan
          , duplicados.LLAVESAP
          , duplicados.DCTOSAP
          , duplicados.FECHASAP
          , duplicados.identificador
          , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by codLote order by (select null)) as row
            FROM dbo.duplicados)
 SELECT c.codlote
      , c.animal
      , c.peso
      , c.pesocava
      , c.fecha
      , c.fechacava
      , c.codtipo
      , c.id
      , c.sexo
      , c.rendimiento
      , c.ciclan
      , c.observaciones
      , c.pesociclan
      , c.LLAVESAP
      , c.DCTOSAP
      , c.FECHASAP
      , c.identificador
        FROM Cte c
        where c.row = 1;
```

Si ejecutas la query tal cual esta planteada, observarás que devuelve dos filas. 1 por cada codlote de los que existen.

[image: Salida]

La gracia de utilizar row_number está, en que esta función numera todas las filas empezando en 1, y reiniciando esta numeración por la columna indicada en partition by. También pueden ser varias columnas, por tanto si fuese, codLote y animal, solo tendrías que separarlas por comas, y entonces te devolvería 4 filas.

Order by debiera de ser determinista, pero como en el caso que planteas no se puede garantizar, directamente le dejamos al motor que determine que fila nos va a devolver como número uno. Podrías cambiar el (select null) por una serie de columnas separadas por coma.

Para ejecutar el delete una vez has confirmado que la lista de selección corresponde a los datos que quieras dejar.

```
WITH Cte
 AS (SELECT duplicados.codlote
          , duplicados.animal
          , duplicados.peso
          , duplicados.pesocava
          , duplicados.fecha
          , duplicados.fechacava
          , duplicados.codtipo
          , duplicados.id
          , duplicados.sexo
          , duplicados.rendimiento
          , duplicados.ciclan
          , duplicados.observaciones
          , duplicados.pesociclan
          , duplicados.LLAVESAP
          , duplicados.DCTOSAP
          , duplicados.FECHASAP
          , duplicados.identificador
          , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by codLote order by (select null)) as row
            FROM dbo.duplicados)
DELETE FROM Cte WHERE row > 1; 
GO
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.duplicados C;
```

Te devuelve las mismas dos filas.